# BASH: Reading Into An Array and Selecting Fields

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sorting, field

I have two questions ...

First, I have a defined set of information that I'm echoing (echo -e) into a file "*/tmp/replacements*" ... (truncated version):

```
"RU_SIT1_CA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nDEV1_DA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nDEV1_DP-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nFTDEV1_DA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nFTDEV1_DP-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nFTSIT1_DA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nFTSIT1_DP-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nSIT1_CA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nDEVX1_CA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nFTDEV1_CA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nDEVX1_DA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nDEVX1_DP-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nSIT1_DA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nSIT1_DP-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nDEV1_CA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nRU_SIT2_CA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nDEV2_DA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nDEV2_DP-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nFTDEV2_DA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nFTDEV2_DP-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nFTSIT2_DA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nFTSIT2_DP-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\nSIT2_CA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000" > "/tmp/replacements"
```

I tried to read that file into an array with:

```
read -a OLDIP "/tmp/replacements"
echo "${OLDIP[@]}"
```

When the script is executed, the shell just hangs without returning. Nothing. I don't understand why. "Bash Cookbook", "ShellCheck", and the "Man page" all say `read -a` should work, with the accompanying `echo "${OLDIP[@]"`.

I have also tried to do it with an `WHILE` loop:

```
while IFS= read -a line
do
    line=$REPLY
done <<< "/tmp/replacements"

echo "${line[@]}"
```

This time, when executed, the shell doesn't  hang, it just doesn't output anything.

If I do it the "Dirty Way" (LOL), it works: `OLDIP=$(cat "/tmp/replacements")` ... since I'm still learning I try and use "Best Practices" whenever possible, and from what I've seen ... although this might not be wrong, there are certainly *better* ways to do it. *(additionally, I think would assign each WORD to elements in the array, when I'm wanting to store LINES)*.

That's the first problem ... now the second ...

The second problem I'm having is how to select a field from the array?

I'm trying to replace IP Addresses in "*/etc/hosts*" ... I want to run the script and say:

```
# search "/etc/hosts" for an IP we have in the array
# if a match is found, perform a SED to replace that
# IP with the IP found in position #3 of that line
# (LB_FQDN,OLDIP,NEWIP)

for i in "${line[@]}"
    do
        grep -q "$i" "/etc/hosts"
            if [[ "$?" -eq "0" ]] #when grep is quiet (-q) exit status 0 means a match was found.
                then
                    sed -i "s/$i/THE-MATCHING-IP-WAS-FOUND,-REPLACE-IT-WITH-THE-SECOND-IP-IN-THAT-SAME-LINE/g" "/etc/hosts"
            fi
    done
```

Assuming I can get my array to actually populate "*the right way*", I would really appreciate some guidance on how to search "/etc/hosts/" for the IP found in field #2 and if found, replace it with the IP on the same line, field #3.

I very much appreciate the help.

Cheers!
-Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read -a OLDIP <<< $(cat /tmp/replacements)
echo "${OLDIP[@]}"

for item in ${OLDIP[@]}
do
   item=( $(echo $item | tr ',' ' ') )
   sed -i "s/${item[1]}/${item[2]}/" /etc/hosts  
done
```

I think that does it. That's assuming there is never a white space in the line data. If there is, you'd have to use the IFS and reset it during the loop to , then set to original before next loop.

Explanation, re comment request:

1. how is "<<<" different from "<" or "<<"
   A. sends the data contained in a variable, in this case: $(cat /tmp/replacements), to whatever will use it.

I've written so much bash that I honestly stopped using certain structures that are hard to read or give unreliable results, or inconsistent. For example, on yours, I tried first < /tmp/replacements but it didn't work. so I just switched to what I always use and what will always work, I noticed on one of my big bash programs there are two places where it uses the < for some data from a file, but I didn't write those lines, and never could really figure out how they worked, or why, lol.

> means: write to file, like: echo yes > file.txt, and creates that file, overwrites the content.

>> means: append to file, which should already exist.

< means read from file, but in a special sense that doesn't do what you expect it to do, or in the way you expect. I never use this, almost never.

<< does not exist.

My io rules are simple: 
> to write to something, and create it / set to null first. 
Except stuff like echo fred >/dev/null of course, which just makes it go away, and stderr/stdout redirects etc.
>> to append to file
<<< to read from anything, if a file, I cat it.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html

```
A here string can be considered as a stripped-down form of a here document.
It consists of nothing more than COMMAND <<< $WORD,
where $WORD is expanded and fed to the stdin of COMMAND.
```

<<< is like piping, but I believe it's more efficient.

```
 cat /etc/hosts | command
 # works much like:
 command <<< $(cat /etc/hosts)
```

Unless of course the function handles files natively, like grep something filename, sed -i 's/stuff/stuff/' filename, etc.

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

if you aren't famililiar with that site, bookmark it, it's one of the best BASH resources out there.

```
0< FILENAME
< FILENAME
  # Accept input from a file.
  # Companion command to ">", and often used in combination with it.
  #
  # grep search-word <filename
```

Even this example is kind of odd, since really you'd do this:

```
grep search-word filename
```

I can't honestly explain what bash does with < filename because I never use that structure, it is not predictable, and I prefer bash to be predictable, so I dumb it down for my use, which works really well by the way. In your case it created an array of 1 item, for example.

2: I see that we are setting the value of "item" as the result of what it found in the array ... how are we certain that our array has LINES and not WORDS?

```
item=( $(echo $item | tr ',' ' ') )
```

item=( word word word word) is the result of this, each resulting array is a line broken into 'words' via the ',' to ' ' translation, from the file, thus, you have a bash array using the default bash internal field separator IFS of ' '.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

read down the page re IFS. IFS is not briefly explainable so unless you have a specific question on it, I'll leave that to the tldp page to explain.

I'm not fully clear on this question. I based my file on the user data sample given, which clearly would never have spaces, aka, words, ie, it's a line. If the data can have spaces, more processing would be required.

```
RU_SIT1_CA-dev.ext.foo.bar.com,123.456.789.000,123.456.789.000\n
```

for example, is a line as given. The domain isn't going to have a space, the IP 1 and 2 are not going to have spaces. I assume these are generated dynamically, so the line is not going to have more words than 1, ie, it's a string with no spaces as provided.

If explicit space handling were required, I would have created the array using an IFS=',' in the loop, then gone on from there. But tr ',' ' ' is the fastest/easiest way to generate a bash space separated array, the bash default.

3. Additionally, I know "tr" is used to TRim input received from the pipe, but is this saying that its trimming the comma and replacing it with nothing?

tr is used to replace single characters, not trim. Think of it this way: tr(anslate), ie, it translates x to y, in this case, ',' to ' '. The comma is not replaced with nothing, it's replaced with ' ', a space.

```
man tr:
NAME
       tr - translate or delete characters
DESCRIPTION
       Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard input, writing to standard output.
```

tr is just the fastest/easiest way to change one character to another in shell.

Here's why I don't use <

```
read -a OLDIP <<< $(cat /tmp/replacements);for item in ${OLDIP[@]}; do item=( $(echo $item | tr ',' ' ') );echo ${item[1]}/${item[2]};done

123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
```

but, using <

```
read -a OLDIP < /tmp/replacements;for item in ${OLDIP[@]}; do item=( $(echo $item | tr ',' ' ') );echo ${item[1]}/${item[2]};done
```

you get:

```
123.456.789.000/123.456.789.000
```

Ie, just one line, either the first or last, probably the last. I believe what happens there is that a new array, OLDIP, is created at every line read, so you end up with only the last line array item, whereas with <<< you are spitting out the entire thing at once, and read takes all the lines at once and does what you expected, create the array with all the lines in it. I tested this with:

```
awk '{print $0}' < /tmp/replacements
```

which works as you'd expect, so this appears to be something specific to read -a. Honestly I would never personally have used read in this way to generate an array, I would have just generated the array directly using another method, but since that was the method you asked the question about, that's the method I figured it would be interesting to find out why it didn't work.

Whereas:

```
<<< $(cat /tmp/replacements)
```

will always, without exception, do precisely what you expected it to do, spit the entire file back to read -a.

I think this answers the rest of your questions.

I've written so absurdly much bash that I no longer use any of its features that are hard to remember, hard to understand, hard to read, or hard to debug, or which don't act the way you expect them to.

Comment: If you are able, could you please expand on this a bit more?  First question ... how is "<<<" different from "<" or "<<" ... I understand basic redirection as it applies to directing STDOUT into a file (>, >>) ... I am less familiar with directing STDIN.

Second question .... I see that we are setting the value of "item" as the result of what it found in the array ... how are we certain that our array has LINES and not WORDS?  Additionally, I know "tr" is used to TRim input received from the pipe, but is this saying that its trimming the comma and replacing it with nothing?

Comment: Wow!  This is beyond amazing. Thank you so much. Yes, I am very familiar with TLDP.org, and reference it regularly.  I "played" with BASH for a few years and only started *using* writing real actual "smart" scripts in 2015. I'd like to think I've taken to it well, always striving to learn "Best Practices" first.  You have provided so much amazing information.  I will be digesting it for a bit. Thanks so much for your effort, I so very much appreciate it!

Comment: For, me, bash best practices are resist bashisms and hard to understand constructions as much as humanly possible, ie, try to make bash look like regular code. Clearly someone here disagrees with that approach judging from the loss of upvote the longer explanation gave. All I can tell you is by strictly followiing the clear, readable, rules, I was able to generate very large bash programs that are in global use today, but which are readable and maintainable, but I am VERY strict with the type of Bash I use, lessons learned very painfully over years.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace that whole question with this awk script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
NR == FNR {
  z[FNR][1]
  split($0, z[FNR], ",")
  next
}
$1 == z[FNR][2] {
  $1 = z[FNR][3]
}
1
```

Then run like this:

```
awk /tmp/replacements /etc/hosts
```

Comment: I am familiar with AWK only in the sense that I can use it as a tool within my scripts to search input for columns or lines, I have not used AWK directly.  Could you provide a link to a tutorial that could walk me through what we see here?  While I greatly appreciate getting the HOW, I am really interested in the WHY behind the HOW.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to continue with `read` instead of `mapfile` or `readarray` you can do this:

```
read -d '' -r -a A < replacements

echo "${A[@]}"
```